Is there a way to render a 16 bit image in gtk
I am making an app that allows me to view an 8-bit image and a 16-bit depth image. The original image is a dicom, therefore the 8-bit one is normalized to those values. The problem is that I realized when I finished that pixbuf is limited to 8 bits and I can't really render the 16 bit image, is there a way in gtk without having to redo all my code to render the 16 bit image?
